# Free monitoring and inventory software like ms system center configuration manager?

Tags: monitoring

Free monitoring and inventory software like ms system center configuration manager?
I know about spiceworks but there you have to log in with account and I don't know if they are sending some of our information online.

Answer (score 4):

I've successfully used OCS Reports and WInventory in the past
links:
http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/ 
http://winventory.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I will check the links 10x

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do with some more detail on what you actually need, SCCM is a big beast.

You might have better luck searching for CMDB software...

I have setup http://www.virtu-al.net/2009/10/26/workstation-server-audit-script-v3/ this in the past.. basic but very useful. It could be modified to output data to a database for you to report from.

Comment: I need software that can tell me for example which workstation what hardware have, how many free disk space have left. Mainly for inventory and monitoring. I have WPKG for remote install. It has to be free and not to require AD, because we have only Samba. If it has only basic features it is good but if it has additional features it is better.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what you want the software to do, you might want to check out OpenNMS. It has inventory tools, but also manages/monitors your environment.

Nagios doesn't really have the inventory features, and you can't scan your network (out of the box), but perhaps it's something you want to check out as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not free, but is cheaper than full SCCM, have you looked at [System Centre Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/essentials.aspx)?

It's a cut-down version of SCCM (and a couple of other System Centre components) that is designed for smaller businesses that don't need/can't afford the full-blown System Centre components.

Comment: I think Essentials requires AD. We don't have AD we have only samba.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite keen on OneCMDB (onecmdb.org), for its easily extensible schema. For monitoring, Nagios is just awesome for its simplicity, and versatility - even if the configuration is awkward..